# JavaScript Objects, Arrays, confusion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My JavaScript MQTT Client (Paho) is subscribed to a Topic on a MQTT Broker (Mosquitto).
I use JSON.parse to convert the array to an object.

```
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
var myObj = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);
```

The payload looks like this,

---

```
{"applicationID":"4","applicationName":"Sensor-Module-241","deviceName":"P-241","devEUI":"00face0173800241","rxInfo":[{"mac":"0004a30b0022813c","rssi":-22,"loRaSNR":10.2,"name":"PiXCL-G000","latitude":45.485524299999994,"longitude":-75.6969496,"altitude":54}],"txInfo":{"frequency":903000000,"dataRate":{"modulation":"LORA","bandwidth":500,"spreadFactor":8},"adr":true,"codeRate":"4/5"},"fCnt":10101,"fPort":99,"data":"AGhQAXMq+AJnAHgDAAEEAAEFAQEGAQEHAgEYCAIB0A==","object":{"digitalInput":{"3":1,"4":1},"digitalOutput":{"5":1,"6":1},"analogInput":{"7":2.8,"8":4.64},"temperatureSensor":{"2":12},"humiditySensor":{"0":40},"barometer":{"1":1100}}}
```

---

Using typeof I get,

---

```
 console.log('payLoadString: ', typeof 'payLoadString');//string
    console.log('message.payloadString: ', typeof message.payloadString);//string
    console.log('myObj: ', typeof myObj);//object
    console.log('myObj.applicationID: ', typeof myObj.applicationID);//string
    console.log('myObj.applicationName: ', typeof myObj.applicationName);//string
    console.log('myObj.deviceName: ', typeof myObj.deviceName);//string
    console.log('myObj.devEUI: ', typeof myObj.devEUI);//string
    console.log('myObj.rxInfo: ', typeof myObj.rxInfo);//object
    console.log('myObj.txInfo: ', typeof myObj.txInfo);//object
    console.log('myObj.fCnt: ', typeof myObj.fCnt);//number
    console.log('myObj.fPort: ', typeof myObj.fPort);//number
    console.log('myObj.data: ', typeof myObj.data);//string
    console.log('myObj.object: ', typeof myObj.object);//object
```

---

If I do the following,

- my first console.log gives me an array???
- I assign that array to a variable
- my second console.log gives me an array???
- my third console.log gives me an object???

I get stuff I do not understand,

```
console.log('Object.entries(myObj): ', Object.entries(myObj));
   var n = Object.entries(myObj);
   console.log('typeof: n: ', n);
   console.log('typeof: Object.entries(myObj): ', typeof Object.entries(myObj));
```

---

```
Object.entries(myObj):  
Array [ […], […], […], […], […], […], […], […], […], […] ]
utility.js:114:2
typeof: n:  
Array [ […], […], […], […], […], […], […], […], […], […] ]
utility.js:116:2
typeof: Object.entries(myObj):  object
```

---

I thought in the beginning that I had used JSON.parse to make the object, but now I don't know what it is.
Then, I wanted to get the information (name:values) contained in rxInfo and also in the ??? that is named object (note: this entry follows the one with the name data) and I want to get the individual name:values from this as well, along with their name:values.

In summary, I want to get the name:value pairs from what I had thought was a json message from the mqtt broker, such that I can use the names in a column in a table and the corresponding values in the adjacent column of the table in a browser.

I keep trying but end up with various things that seem so weird.
For instance, this Object.entries(myObj.rxInfo[0]) gives me

```
Array [ […], […], […], […], […], […], […] ]
```

and I can get the length, and use Object.entries(), Object.keys() and Object.values() on this, but when I try to access a specific entry using a string key,
`console.log(Object.entries(myObj.rxInfo[0].rssi))`, I end up with

```
Array []
```

and when I do this,

```
console.log(Object.entries(myObj.rxInfo[0]).rssi);
```

I end up with

```
undefined
```

ARRGGGHHHH!
I must admit I am not very knowledgeable about JavaScript, but had thought that this would not be very hard, and it's turning out to be quite confusing.

Comment: `typeof <array>` returns `"object"` because an array is just an object with a few special properties.

Comment: [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns an array, hence why you get an array.... typeof by the way doesn't give a `"array"` type string. Array's are just specialized objects hence why it gives `"object"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `typeof` on an array will return object which leads to confusion, in the example you provided `rxInfo` is an array. You can try `myObj.rxInfo[0].rssi` and you should see the value you expected.

You can check if the object is an actual array using [isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) or testing the prototype
`Object.prototype.toString.call(data) == '[object Array]';`

Comment: That is the answer. As a beginner I find the concepts that I encountered here to be confusing. I suppose I was overthinking this and trying to make use of complex methods to solve the problem. In my non-understanding, as I was seeing something so close as to what I wanted I had thought the problem was far too complex for me. I know I should avoid saying thanks, but golly, thanks.